# What's the greatest value for postgres maintenance_work_mem?

Tags: postgresql

I set `1960MB` successfully for `maintenance_work_mem`, and got about 30% performance improvement on my `COPY` batch inserts.

So I'm trying to run the import with even more mem (my machine has 32GB).
Problem: Whenever I set any greater value, eg 2500MB, the postgres x64 server won't start up.

Do I have to configure another property? Or is it just not supported to give the mem values of 2GB+?

Comment: Sorry, I ment I got an improvement on `indexing` after a copy without indexes.

Comment: @membersound check your PostgreSQL server's log. It should say why it's not starting up.

Comment: I have installed the x64 version on an x64 system. Anyhow I can only use `2000MB` (not 2GB, and not 2001MB). Why?

Comment: There is a 2GB limit on Windows (even for 64bit), which does not apply to Linux: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFWQgO=fgsniCMvNiReVdcBc9+hB6N0b8SFVCY9xOjQpP=GSmQ@mail.gmail.com

Comment: Try to run postgres and paste logs... this may help to solve Your problem